# How can I get a PieChart to be colored as I wish?

Tags: color, plotting

How to use the value of a funtion[label] to assign color to a piece of the pie?

(edited after answer of kguler )
My dude is how to control the colors in ranges of a function of [labels]

In this way I can show:
1.- the percentage of Data(labels), using pieces of pie and
2.- the value f of labels, with range colors (similar to TemperatureMap but customized)

[image: Use a funcion of Data-Labels to control the color os pieces]

------ Original Post ------

I want to use a "gradient" or "a reduce (5-6) list of colors"(similar to DarkRainbow with a little colors)?

I was trying with ColorData and ColorDataFunction ( [here you can see that I obtain errors with the same code as the reference doc](http://sensa.square7.ch/gfdgdfgdf06.jpg) ) but I have no succes!!

```
percent = {12, 18, 24, 46}
labels = {1, 9, 15, 22}
f = {8, 7, 1, 4}
PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, ImageSize -> 200, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad",  ChartStyle -> ColorData["TemperatureMap" {0, 8}]]
PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, ImageSize -> 200, PlotLabel -> "Test-Comic", ChartStyle -> ColorData[9, "ColorList"]]
```

In the image you can see any more about explanation:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I think you are after something like

```
 pc3b = PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, 
   PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad-3b", ImageSize -> 300,
   ChartStyle -> {ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 8}}] /@ f}]
```

[image]

Similar trick with `ColorFunction` should work too...

```
rule = Thread[percent -> f];
PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad-4b", 
 ImageSize -> 300,  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 8}}][#1 /. rule] &)]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
percent = {12, 18, 24, 46};
labels = {1, 9, 15, 22};
f = {8, 7, 1, 4};
pc1 = PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad-1", 
  ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"];
pc2 = PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad-2",
  ImageSize -> 200,  ColorFunction -> 
        Function[{angle}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][angle]]];
(*the following based on guessing how you might want to use color gradients with `f` *)
pc3 = PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad-3", 
  ImageSize -> 200, ChartStyle -> {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] & /@ Rescale[f]}];
pc4 = PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad-4", 
  ImageSize -> 200, ColorFunction -> Function[{angle},
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Nearest[Rescale[f], angle]]]];
pc5 = PieChart[percent, ChartLabels -> labels, PlotLabel -> "Test-Comic", 
  ImageSize -> 200,  ChartStyle -> 9];
Row[{pc1, pc2, pc3, pc4, pc5}, Spacer[5]] // Panel
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I think that´s the good way. f must be a parameter because the color depends on its value. I´m making a image to concrete more. I post in a few minutes

Comment: Here are any aditional precisions, http://sensa.square7.ch/gdfgdfgd10.jpg

Comment: Yes :-) , your answer is the cuasi-solution!! It works well and gives similar colors to similar values, and equale colors to equal values of f[label]. But the only detail I would like to control (if possible) is: 1.- define the colors (with CMYK or RGB code) and 2.- the ranges of values of f.

Comment: I was seeing that red (how much red, f much high) and warm colors indicate that f is over the mean; and blue(how much blue, much low) and cold colors indicate the lowest values. And I can Reverse colors. If you can show me how to control colors and ranges(as explains in a previous image-link), fantastic; if not, this may be the solution for me, and I´m mark the question solved by you.

Comment: @MikaIke, it would be a good idea to avoid questions and answers that keep getting larger/longer :) If the answer is ok for the original version of your question, I suggest you post a new question focusing on the new parts.

Comment: Really The answer doesn´t solve totally the initial question, because we can´t still control de range of colors what we want(you can see the "violet schemes"-5 tones). But I think that your answer is good!, and in my case could solve (not exactly what I wanted, but...could be operative) partial my question. I put it solved, but if someone know what control 5 ranges of values of f, I´m grtefull for the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MikaIke. I'll see if I can find a way to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
PieChart[{10, 20, 40}, ChartLabels -> {"Blah", "blah", "blahhh"}, 
 ImageSize -> 200, PlotLabel -> "Test-Grad", 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]]
```

[image]

Note there is no color scheme called "gradient" - there is a *class* of schemes called *gradients*, you can use `ColorData["Gradients"]` to see the particular named schemes.

If you want more control over colors assigned, point `ColorFunction` to your own function that does whatever is needed to the data and returns the appropriate color(s).

Comment: No, The colors depends on the value os a function of the labels. In your example, if F(Blah)=100,F(blahhh)=95,F(blah)=50 . The colors of the piece of Blah has the same (or close/similar) of the piece of blahhhh, because the value of F(Blah) and F(blahhhh) is similar.

If you use this colors http://sensa.square7.ch/hgfhgfg.jpg , Blah and blahh have, the two, a darker color , while the other is ligther. In this way you can show 2 dimensions of data (one with the percent and other with the color.)

Comment: @MikaIke as I said, point it to your own color function definition. The above is just showing correct usage of the basic form which you have completely wrong in your example image. Read the documentation, everything needed is there.

Comment: I was seeing the documentation (ColorData, colorFunction, and any more) but I can´t understand how to do that question. I continue reading about the issue but  Only to put any colors, but in your example how do you put similar colors to "Blah" and "blahhh"(supossing that f[Blah] and f[blahhh] is close)?. using Color functions.